# Ethers.js - Sent Matic to 'undefined' has created a contract

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, polygon

Using ethers.js I have sent Matic to an undefined address and it created a contract on my behalf before mining the transaction. I’m wondering if there’s any fallback function that’s created by default that will allow the owner to withdraw the funds? Here’s the code:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('https://polygon-mainnet.infura.io/v3/{apiKey}’);
const signer = new ethers.Wallet({walletKey}, provider)

const address = undefined //undefined value passed here in error

const tx = await signer.sendTransaction({
            to: address,
            value: ethers.utils.parseEther(`1`),
            maxFeePerGas,
            maxPriorityFeePerGas
        });
        tx.wait();
```

I have reproduced an example of a contract being created and holding funds which you can [view by clicking here](https://polygonscan.com/address/0x72ab715ec6eb37e9414a533f7a7ca4bbadeb9202)

Answer (score 1):

That's perfectly normal, that's what sending a transaction without specifying a recipient does, it creates a contract, and if there's no data sent with that transaction, it creates an empty contract. And no, your matic is stuck there, unfortunately. There's no "default method" of any kind in a smart contract, or even a concept of an "owner" by default, a contract does what it's been coded to do, nothing more, nothing less (and in that case, well, nothing at all)